# How do I access Members in a Pointer to Structs?

Tags: c

In my header I have:

```
#define MAXSTRSIZE 20
struct Account{
    char* Name;
    char* Password;
};
```

and in my main function I have:

```
struct Account* const AccountList=malloc(sizeof(struct Account)*AccountAmount)//AccountAmount is just an int value input by the user
FILE* File = fopen(FileName,"r");
int Counter;//Counter for the For Loop
for (Counter=0;Counter<AccountAmount;Counter++)
{
    *(AccountList+Counter).Name=malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXSTRSIZE);
    *(AccountList+Counter).Password=malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXSTRSIZE);
    fscanf(File,"%s%s",*(AccountList+Counter).Name,*(AccountList+Counter).Password);
```

When I compile I get the following error "error: request for member 'Name' in something not a structure or union". How do I actually fill my allocated space with structs that contain the members?

Comment: You could also write (*(AccountList+Counter)).Name... but do use AccountList[Counter].Name for readability...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
*(AccountList+Counter)
```

to

```
AccountList[Counter]
```

or

```
(*(AccountList+ Counter)).
```

This is my solution

```
struct Account* const AccountList=malloc(sizeof(struct Account)*AccountAmount);//AccountAmount is just an int value input by the user
    FILE* File = fopen(FileName,"r");
    int Counter;//Counter for the For Loop
    for (Counter=0;Counter<AccountAmount;Counter++)
    {
        AccountList[Counter].Name = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXSTRSIZE);
        AccountList[Counter].Password = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXSTRSIZE);
        fscanf(File,"%19s%19s", AccountList[Counter].Name,AccountList[Counter].Password);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using array notation?

Comment: @DustinH: why would you not want to use array notation when accessing an array?  Pointers are great, but so are arrays.  Use array notation because it is more compact, if nothing else; it is also generally clearer.

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices to get rid of this error. Access struct members Name or Password either using

```
(AccountList+Counter)->Name 
(AccountList+Counter)->Password
```

or

```
AccountList[Counter].Name
AccountList[Counter].Password
```

Replace either of the two mentioned above in your entire code.

Comment: The arrow notation is interesting and not mentioned in other answers.  Well spotted!

Answer (score 1):

You should either use

```
AccountList[Counter].Name
```

or

```
(*(AccountList + Counter)).Name
```

Comment: You *should* use the first one, but you *could* use the second one. :-)